# Turning public my Facebook App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm having a problem with the Facebook API.
As a Facebook Developer (or admin), i can access my app with no problem or errors.
But, when i'm try to access using a non-developer account i have the following error:

> (GraphMethodException - #100) Unsupported get request.

I already have disabled the SandBox mode, than my app is public.
And i changed the permissions to 'anyone (13+)'

Could you guys help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue guys.

In **'Config -> Advanced'** panel, the option **'Country Restricted'** it was marked as Yes, and the Country selected was Brazil.
I just set the **'Country Restricted'** to NO, and the app works fine to everyone